# Generate XML parser from DTD for Java?

Tags: java, parsing, dtd

I have a DTD that I expect to evolve over time. E.g. JAXB can construct an object model from this DTD. That's useful. However, I would like a tool that can construct an entire parser for XML documents matching this DTD. This can be a parser that simply generates and returns an object tree. Since I expect to write code using the resulting objects, getting Java source or class files that an IDE can understand would be helpful.

I can't seem to find such a tool. Similar beasts seem to exist for XML Schemas.

Does anyone know of an open source tool that can create parsers from a DTD?

Comment: Why do you think you need to generate a specific parser?  Why won't a `DocumentBuilder` with `isValidating(true)` do what you  need?

Comment: I believe you actually mean "marshaller/unmarshaller" rather than "parser". And are you sure that JAXB doesn't give you this?

Comment: Hm, terminology. It does indeed look like xjc + JaxbContext.createUnmarshaller() would do the trick. @parsifal: plz write an answer that I can accept.